# Not mapping all fields from html to controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to update my category object

my  model:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private Long created;
    private Long updated;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Long created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Long getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Long updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Here my controller:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

    // If class has only one constructore then @Autowired wiil execute automatically
    public CategoryController(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        createStubCategoryList();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/category")
        public String submitCategory(Category category, Model model) {
            logger.info("updateCategory = " + category);
            model.addAttribute("submitted", true);
            model.addAttribute("category", category);
            categoryRepository.save(category);
            return "category";
        }

        @RequestMapping("category/edit/{id}")
        public String editCategory(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
            Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
            logger.info("find_category = " + category);
            model.addAttribute("category", category);
            return "category";
        }
```

Here my template to edit category:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Category template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${category}" th:action="@{/category}">
        <h3>Category</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description of the category" rows="5" id="description"
                  th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="result_message" th:if="${submitted}">
        <h3>Your category has been submitted.</h3>
        <p>Find all categories <a href="/categories">here</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When call method in log has:

```
[INFO ] 2020-01-07 19:38:07.493 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] CategoryController - find_category = Optional[
Category{id=2, name='Electronics', created=1578418669105, updated=null, description='Electronics's description'}]
```

and here screen:

[image]

As you can see the field **created=1578418669105**

Nice.

Now I edit name "Electronics" to "Electronics2" and click submit.
As result call method: `submitCategory` in my controller. Nice.

Here result in log:

```
[INFO ] 2020-01-07 19:40:23.327 [http-nio-8090-exec-2] CategoryController - updateCategory = 
Category{id=0, name='Electronics2', created=null, updated=null, description='Electronics's description'}
```

but as you can see the field **created**  is null. Why?

I need to update only editable fields: **name** and **description**.

Another fields (like **created, updated, id**) must  not change. This fields are not mapped.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Because created, updated, id you need to pass as hidden. It is not available in html page.

Comment: In my model has many fields (10). But in html I need to show only 2 fields. But when click submit I need to pass all fields of model. How I can do this?  So I need to set 8 fields as hidden?

Comment: keep hidden on html page with value

Answer (score 0):

Each column should be changed to updatable to `false` because by default is `true`.

```
@Column(name = "created", updatable = false)
private Long created;
```

Comment: Not help. Same result.

Comment: That is really weird. OK I did a check and you don't save it here:
           `Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
            logger.info("find_category = " + category);
            model.addAttribute("category", category);` only you are getting the object found

Comment: In method "editCategory" I only need to find category by id and pass it to html. Why in this method I need to save category to repository?